# Google Data Flow error: NameError: global name 'itertools' is not defined

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, python-itertools

I am trying to run Apache Beam program on Google Cloud.

Now, in the pipeline, I am calling the *join_lists()* function
In this function, I am using itertools.product but I am getting the error message :

**Error message**

```
NameError: global name 'itertools' is not defined [while running 'FlatMap(join_lists)']
```

**Code**

```
def join_lists((k,v)):
    itertools.product(v['master_data'], v['new_data'])
```

**Main function :**

```
joined_dicts = (
    {'master_data' :master_data, 'new_data' : new_data }
    | beam.CoGroupByKey()
    | beam.FlatMap(join_lists)
    | 'mergeddicts' >> beam.Map(lambda (masterdict, newdict): new_dict.update(master_dict))
)
```

I have already imported itertools

```
import itertools
```

Comment: do you use a variable called itertools in your code? Try importing itertools inside the function right before the call

Comment: or just do `[(a, b) for a in v['master_data'] for b in v['new_data']]`. I hope I understood `itertools.product` correctly

Comment: yes, it worked. thanks. I think when Dataflow spawns and runs the function on worker node, the import was not applicable. adding the import inside the function, did the trick. thanks a lot.

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened. (I downvoted this time, in the hope that you will remember for your next question).